# NSPredicate not filtering as desired

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate

Consider the following array:

```
NSArray *dataValues = @[@"Foo[0]", @"Foo[1].bar"];
```

And the following regex pattern, predicate and expected output:

```
NSString *pattern = @"Foo[0]";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", pattern];
NSArray *results = [dataValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSLog(@"matches = %ld", (long)results.count);
```

This prints `1` in the console as expected. If we change the pattern to:

```
NSString *pattern = @"Foo\\[[0-9]\\]";
```

I would expect this to print `2` in the console, but it prints `0`. I have double escaped the outer square brackets to allow them to be parsed and expect to find strings that have the numbers 0 to 9 inside the brackets to match this expression.

I have checked the regex against the following site, which does work correctly:

> http://regexr.com/3bcut

I have no warnings/errors in Xcode (6.4, 6E35b) running against the iOS 8.4 iPhone 6 Plus simulator, but why does my regex not filter as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After raising a TSI with Apple (well, who uses those things anyway?) they said I simply needed to use `MATCHES` instead of `BEGINSWITH`, which is only used for string matching - whereas I am trying to match on a regex.

My predicate should have therefore read:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", pattern];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this depending on what your needs are:

```
    NSArray *dataValues = @[@"Foo[0]", @"Foo[1].bar"];
    NSString *pattern = @"Foo[*]*";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF LIKE %@", pattern];
    NSArray *results = [dataValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
    NSLog(@"matches = %ld", (long)results.count);
```

You could go a little more basic and use

```
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *str in dataValues) {
        if ([str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
            if ([str hasPrefix:@"Foo["]) {
                [results addObject:str];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"matches = %ld", (long)results.count);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I can understand alternative ways to do this using string prefix checking (et al) but the integer inside the square brackets will need to be a dynamic range, eg 0-9, 10-19 etc as the code is inside a for loop - but what frustrates me is why my regex doesn't work! Perhaps a bug?